# Прилично = неприлично?

Tags: семантика, антонимы

«*Я пил, достаточно прилично пил.*»

По этой фразе, недолго рассуждая, легко сделать вывод о полном стирании границы у ***прилично-неприлично*** как пары безусловных антонимов. Смысл не поменяется, скажи он: «*Я пил неприлично много*». Когда же это произошло, а главное — как?

Answer (score 3):

Разные значения. Хотя оба переносные. Забавное совпадение, не более.
Прилично (пил) - это "много" или даже "хорошо". Изначально у этого значения "прилично" был смысл "столько, что не стыдно сказать, вынести на публику", но потом выхолостилось до простого "достаточно много" - и исходная "приличность" тут уже не задействована.

А во втором случае "неприлично" хотя несет переносное значение, с исходным "(не)прилично" = (не)подобающе связи не утратило.

Другими словами, **в этих значениях *прилично* и *неприлично*** **не являются** антонимами изначально.

Разумеется, это не отменяют антонимичность "прилично" и "неприлично" в основных значениях.

Answer (score 1):

Да, я пил, и **достаточно прилично** пил. Но буквально в феврале меня осенило: 63 года, думаю, может быть хватит», — говорит Анатолий Пименов.

Прилично — это **достойно**, потом **хорошо, много** (разг.). Например: прилично (= достаточно много) зарабатывать. И **прилично** пить — это тоже **много** пить.

С другой стороны, пьянство осуждается обществом, **поэтому пить прилично (= много)  — это неприлично.**

В данном примере **противопоставлено** изначальное (прямое) значение слова **прилично** (соответствие приличиям) его вторичному (переносному) значению (много). Зарабатывать много (прилично) — это хорошо, прилично, а пить много (прилично) — это уже неприлично.

Из словаря:

ПРИЛИЧИЕ, -я; ср. 1. Вежливость, пристойность в поведении, в словах. П. требует, заставляет. Для, ради приличия. Из приличия нанести визит. 2. только мн.: приличия, -ий. Правила поведения, принятые в какой-л. общественной среде. Пренебречь приличиями. Соблюдать приличия. Нарушать приличия. Видимость приличий.

ПРИЛИЧНЫЙ,  1. Соответствующий приличиям; пристойный. П-ые манеры. П-ое поведение. // Вполне достойный, порядочный. П. человек. П-ая девушка. **2. Разг. Достаточно хороший, удовлетворительный.** П. костюм. П. заработок. П-ая мебель, обстановка. <Прилично, нареч. П. одеваться. П. зарабатывать. П. чувствовать себя.

Comment: Ну какое еще осуждение обществом? "(Не)прилично хорошо пел" - тот же случай.

Comment: Он пьет  неприлично много (= очень много) - это осуждение обществом, несоответствие приличиям.  Он пьет достаточного прилично (= достаточно много) - это просто утверждение.